# Is a program that finds all pythagorean triples Involving one number useful?

Tags: prime-numbers, pythagorean-triples

I created a program that quickly finds all the pythagorean triples for one number (up to about 14 digits currently). Is this useful or is it fairly obvious to do? I'm a lay person in math but love patterns, numbers and research. If it's useful I will make it available. 
Example: all of the pythagorean triples for: 
29173 (prime):
 $29173^2 = 27948^2 + 8365^2$ 
$29173^2 + 425531964^2 = 425531965^2$

Or the number 221: 
$221^2 = 204^2 + 85^2$ 
$221^2 = 195^2 + 104^2$ 
$221^2 = 171^2 + 140^2$ 
$221^2 + 60^2 = 229^2$ 
$221^2 + 1428^2 = 1445^2$ 
$221^2 + 1872^2 = 1885^2$ 
 $221^2 + 24420^2 = 24421^2$

Comment: Congrats on the work, but a lot is already known about how to do this. It is unlikely to be new.

Comment: At heart, all pythagorean triples can be written as uniquely as $(a,b,c)=(2uvw,w(u^2-v^2),w(u^2+v^2))$ where $u,v,w$ are positive integers, $\gcd(u,v)=1,$ $u>v$ and $u,v$ are not both odd. So solving our problem amounts to factoring $n$ for the cases $a=n$ or $b=n.$ This is also true for $c=n,$ but less obviously.

Comment: So there is no triple for $a=221.$ For $b=221=13\cdot 17,$ you get $(u,v,w)=(15,2,1),(7,6,17),(9,8,13).$. For $c=221,$ you get solutions $(u,v,w)=(3,2,17),(4,1,13)$ and a pair of solutions where $w=1.$ $(11,10,1)$ and $14,5,1).$

Comment: Whoops, missed one case of $b=221,$ $(u,v,w)=111,110,1).$

Comment: In particular, you seem to have missed the case $221^2=220^2+21^2$

Comment: Sorry -- I missed writing 221^2 = 220^2 + 21^2 in the example but it was in the results of my program.

Comment: @pattern_mancer Do let people know if their comments or answers are useful or correct so they can know if you need more help or not.

Comment: @pattern_mancer Your program missed the primitive triple: $(21,220,221)$. Also,
 $(195,104,221)=13\times(15,8,17)$ and
 $(85,204,221) =17\times(5,12,13).\quad$ I’m sure there are other omissions and imprimitives but these were easy to spot.

Answer (score 1):

The “interesting” triples are the "primitives" and there are many ways to find these, even among the related links to the right of this page. All others can be found using the factors of "given" numbers.

Things to keep in mind are:

1. Side A can be any odd number greater than one.
2. Side B can be any multiple of four.
3. Side C "must" be of the form $\,4n+1\,$ but not all such numbers qualify for primitives.
   [Here](https://oeis.org/A020882) is a list of the first couple of dozen primitive hypotenuse values.

If you like patterns, note that primitives (and a few imprimitives) can be grouped into sets with at least 2 common  attributes in each row and column of the sample table below. If you study the patterns, you may see how the formula that generates them was developed.

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
n & k=1 & k=2 & k=3 & k=4 & k=5  \\ \hline
Set_1 & 3,4,5 & 5,12,13& 7,24,25& 9,40,41& 11,60,61  \\ \hline
Set_2 & 15,8,17 & 21,20,29 &27,36,45 &33,56,65 & 39,80,89  \\ \hline
Set_3 & 35,12,37 & 45,28,53 &55,48,73 &65,72,97 &  75,100,125 \\ \hline
Set_{4} &63,16,65 &77,36,85 &91,60,109 &105,88,137 &119,120,169 \\ \hline
Set_{5} &99,20,101 &117,44,125 &135,72,153 &153,104,185 &171,140,221 \\ \hline
\end{array}

If Euclid's formula is considered functions of $(m,k)$, then these were generated with the same functions using
$\big((2n-1+k),k\big)$ which resolve to.

\begin{align*}
&A=(2n-1)^2+&&2(2n-1)k\\
&B=               &&2(2n-1)k+2k^2\\
&C=(2n-1)^2+&&2(2n-1)k+2k^2
 \end{align*}

Comment: I mentioned there are many ways of finding these triples. A few ways are shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3703421/how-to-find-pythagorean-triples-with-one-side-only?rq=1).

Comment: In each row, the increment between A-values is
$\, (2n-1)\,$ and $\,C-B=(2n-1)^2.\quad$
In each column, the increment between B-values is 
$\,4k\,$ and $\,C-A=2k^2.$

Comment: Thank you poetasis for that information. I had noticed the pattern that you mentioned above. So essentially for mathematicians, this is not necessarily useful, but for lay people interested in finding pythagorean triples quickly, it may be.

Comment: @pattern_mancer In 2009, in this table, I saw $A_{k+1}-A_k=(2n-1)$, $C-B=(2n-1)^2$, and $A=(2n-1)^2+(2n-1)^2k.$ I derived $B$ and $C$ by substituting this into the Pythagorean equation. Here is another derived relationship:

Observation:$\quad \text{inradius}=r=(2n -1)k.\quad$

Proof: We let inradius(r)=area(a)/semiperimeter(s)
 and we let $j=(2n-1)$

$$a=\dfrac{AB}{2}
=\dfrac{(j^2+2jk)(2jk+2k^2)}{2}
=jk(j^2+3jk+2k^2)$$

$$s=\dfrac{A+B+C}{2}
=\dfrac{(j^2+2jk)+(2jk+2k^2)+(j^2+2jk+2k^2)}{2}
=j^2+3jk+2k^2$$

$$r=\dfrac{a}{s}
=\dfrac{jk(j^2+3jk+2k^2)}{(j^2+3jk+2k^2)}=jk
=(2n-1)k$$